# Etust ITM server in a Virtual Environment

Tags: virtualization, anti-virus

Has anyone got Etrust ITM server 8.1 r1 working on a virtual server.
I have tried 2008r2, server 2008 standard, server 2003 and still the console and client agent freezeup.
Computer Associates wont support it because it is on a virtual Machine.

I am not running a seperate box just for an ITM server, I would sooner switch AV then do this.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this setup lives in a corporation.  Etrust is an awful anti-virus.  We have recently purged etrust from our environment.  We now use Symantec Endpoint Protection. You would not believe the crap it found that etrust let in.

CA obviously doesn't care about the future of your company.  VM's are not coming, they are already here.  VM's need antivirus if they are running windows.

I would ween my company off any CA dependencies.

Comment: I agree I am looking to a new solution...I have a new question started for opinions on a product. Thanks